# Modal box to play music from a database

Tags: php, html, sql, database, modal-dialog

I'm making a jukebox for my Uni assignment and I want a Modal Box to pop up when the play button is clicked with the song in the Modal Box on autoplay.

I know how to autoplay, however, this is being pulled from a database, an SQL one I think?

At the moment it sort of works, with the pop up box showing (sometimes) but then it takes me to another page that shows the player at the bottom of the page, whereas I want it in the actual box, hopefully I'm making sense.

Below is the picture of what I want it to look like because it sometimes works if you go back and forth a few times.

[image]

The code that I think has everything apart from my css is below.

How do I keep the music player in the modal box without it going to a different ID page?

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "music";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM music_tbl";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    echo "<table border='1'>";
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 echo "<tr><td><img width='150' height='140'src=/Music_Player/songimages/". $row['album_cover_url'].">" .
     "</td><td>" . $row["track_name"] .
     "</td><td>" . $row["singers"] .
     "</td><td>" . $row["album_name"] .   
     "</td><td>" . $row["trackID"] . 
     "</td><td><a href=jukebox.php?trackID=". $row["trackID"] ."> <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id='myBtn'><img src=playButton.png class='playB'></button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id='myModal' class='modal'>

 <!-- Modal content -->
 <div class='modal-content'>
     <span class='close'>x</span>
  <audio controls>
 <source src='songs/". $row['song_file_link'] ."' type='audio/mpeg'>

Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
 </div>

 </div> </a>
     </td></tr>";
     }
    echo "</table>";             

} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: What's the question/problem here?

Comment: Okay so I did ask the question but it's deleted itself? Basically I want to know how to keep the player in the modal box without it trying to go to a different page when I press the play button